# What is the strength of gravity compared to electromagnetism?

Tags: electromagnetism, newtonian-gravity, estimation, interactions

I would like to know the strength of gravity as compared to electromagnetism. Im not looking for their classical constant values. It can be compared by saying i.e. gravity is a million billion times weaker etc with the specific numbers. thanks to all those that answer.

Comment: I'd suggest thay you calculate the gravitational and electrostatic attractive forces between an electron and a proton and compare the values.

Comment: look at the coupling constants  http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Forces/funfor.html

Answer (score 1):

Here is a quick and simple way to compare the relative strengths of gravity and electromagnetism:

Take two electrons. Place them 1 centimeter apart and measure how strongly they repel one another via electrostatics. Then, knowing their masses, calculate how strongly they attract one another due to gravity.

How far apart would you need to separate the electrons, so that the *magnitude* of the electrostatic force between them is then about the same as the *magnitude* of the gravitational force between them at a distance of 1 centimeter? 1.8 light years.

Comment: Huh? Both the electromagnetic force and the gravitational force scale as $1/r^2$. So it doesn't matter how far you separate the electrons, the electrostatic force is much greater.

Comment: my example illustrates the difference in the size of the *coupling constants* by changing the *distance* scale.

Comment: I read your answer too fast, obviously. Apologies.

Comment: my apologies ive been out of town on business. let me rephrase, compared to gravity how much stronger is the force of electromagnetism? physicists have worked out all these calculations so im looking for something short and sweet. my time is limited to go digging up answers online. i consider physics stack exchange an awesome resource. perhaps people i meet here that take time to help me dig up answers i need .. i will give you credit as acknowledgement on work im doing that will eventually be published

Answer (score -2):

Gravity is a million billion billion billion times smaller, or thereabouts.

Comment: what is that? 10 to the negative 23 power?

Comment: I meant negative 33 power